# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable - when attempting to start a new session

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run my tests on Chrome I often get a WebdriverException that Chrome is not reachable. It doesn't happen every time. Maybe once every 15 times. I am having to run everything on Windows machines and I have the latest Chrome, Chromedriver, Selenium-Webdriver versions.

I've tried setting the environmental variable "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null". Doesn't help at all.

Anyone come across this and found a solution?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 62.52 seconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'CORPMNA7158A', ip: '10.26.195.163', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error does gives us some hint as follows :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
```

Which essentially implies that `chromedriver` binary is unable to spawn a new `Chrome Browser` process.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **`chromedriver=2.35.528161`** (released `2018-01-10`)
- Release Notes of [**`chromedriver=2.35`**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v62-64`**

- You mentioned of using latest Chrome. I suppose it is **`chrome=65.x`**
- You are using **`Selenium Version 2.52.0`** (released **2016-02-11 11:22:43**) [`as per the error stack trace within your question`]

So the time gap between the release of **`Selenium Version 2.52.0`** and **`chromedriver=2.35.528161`** is almost **2 Years** and are not compatible. Hence **`ChromeDriver`** is unable to spawn the new `Chrome Browser` process at times.

### Solution

- Keep the `ChromeDriver` at  **`v2.35`** level.
- Downgrade `Chrome` to  stable **`Chrome v64.x`** levels. ([`as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes`](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- Upgrade `Selenium` to  current levels **`Version 3.8.1`**.
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: That was it. I just inherited this project and didn't notice Selenium was so out of date. Updated to latest version and problem went away.