# Am I using right piece of code for getting the output of a registration page in a text file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Am very new to automation and am trying to automate a registration page and get the output in a text file using cucumber framework. but it seems my Then part does not have right piece of code and also getting the following error : 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element
Below are details:
Feature: Customer Registration
Scenario Outline: Validation of the registration form 
 Given I am able to access customer registration form
 When I try to fill in ""  ""  and ""
 And I click on Submit
 Then I should be able to navigate to Registered Successfully page with customer details

```
        Examples: 
        | customerName  | age | address | phoneNumber  | email     |
        | testuserOne   | 21  | London  | 789456123    |xyz@xyz.com|
        | testuserTwo   | 23  | Paris   | 789456128    |xvyxvy.com |



    Step file:



package StepDefintion;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import java.io.*;


public class stepDefintion{

    WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^I am able to access customer registration form$")
    public void i_am_able_to_access_customer_registration_form() throws Throwable 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\learning\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.get("http://apps.e-box.co.in/CustomerRegistration/Index");

    }

    @When("^I try to fill in \"([^\"]*)\" (\\d+) \"([^\"]*)\" (\\d+) and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_try_to_fill_in_and(String arg1, int arg2, String arg3, int arg4, String arg5) throws Throwable 
    {
      driver.findElement(By.name("cname")).sendKeys(arg1);
      driver.findElement(By.name("age")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(arg2));
      driver.findElement(By.name("address")).sendKeys(arg3);
      driver.findElement(By.name("phonenumber")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(arg4));
      driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(arg5);

    }

    @When("^I click on Submit$")
    public void i_click_on_Submit() throws Throwable 
    {
     driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
    }



    @Then("^I should be able to navigate to Registered Succesfully page with customer details$")
    public void i_should_be_able_to_navigate_to_Registered_Succesfully_page_with_customer_details() throws Throwable, IOException 
    {
        String S1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h2[normalize-space()='Registered Succesfully']//following::td[2]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");       

        File file = new File ("D:\\learning\\CucumberParameterization\\src\\output.txt");
        FileWriter FW = new FileWriter (file);
        PrintWriter PW = new PrintWriter (FW);

        PW.print(S1);

        PW.close();

    }


}




        Error Stack Trace :

            org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
      (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 4.01 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
    System info: host: '****', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73), userDataDir=***\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir8160_2912}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=64.0.3282.167, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
    Session ID: cf56a3d609cb4b5dd6b20413ec2fbdab
    *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h2[normalize-space()='Registered Succesfully']//following::td[2]}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:358)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:861)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:859)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
        at StepDefintion.stepDefintion.i_should_be_able_to_navigate_to_Registered_Succesfully_page_with_customer_details(stepDefintion.java:50)
        at ?.Then I should be able to navigate to Registered Succesfully page with customer details(D:/learning/CucumberParameterization/src/featureFiles/Customer.feature:8)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementExeption, selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"}
```

Seems *WebDriver* instance is unable to locate the *WebElement* and you may require to induce some [*WebDriverWait*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) for the element to be **visible** as follows :

```
String S1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h2[normalize-space()='Registered Succesfully']//following::td[2]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [*NoSuchElementException*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexeption-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

---

### Update A :

As per your comment now you are seeing the following error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 4.01 seconds Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46' *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h2[normalize-space()='Registered Succesfully']//following::td[2]}
```

The main reason is the binaries you are using are not compatible as :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **Supports Chrome v60-62**

- Your *Chrome Browser* version is **63.x**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser*

### Solution

- Upgrade your *ChromeDriver* to recent *ChromeDriver=2.35* level.
- As per the Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) upgrade your *Chrome Browser* to *Chrome v62-64* levels.
- If your base *Chrome Browser* version is too old uninstall *Chrome Browser* through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent released GA version of *Chrome Browser*
- Execute your *Tests*

---

### Update B :

As per your comment as you are seeing the error as :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 4.01 seconds Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.35.528161
```

- You are using *Selenium Version* **2.47.1** (released **2015-07-30 02:56:46**) [as per the error stack trace within your question]
- So the time gap between the release of *Selenium Version 2.52.0* and *ChromeDriver=2.35* is almost 3 Years and are **incompatible**. Hence *ChromeDriver* is unable to spawn the new *Chrome Browser* process.

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to current levels **Version 3.9.1**
- You can find a detailed discussion in [*Chromedriver frequently hangs when attempting to start a new session. Chrome not reachable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323856/chromedriver-frequently-hangs-when-attempting-to-start-a-new-session-chrome-not/48328964#48328964)

Comment: Sorry but this isnt helping as well, getting below errors:  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4.01 seconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h2[normalize-space()='Registered Succesfully']//following::td[2]}

Comment: Added an update to my answer. let me know the status.

Comment: Did what you mentioned. it didnt work:- org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4.01 seconds

Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.35.528161

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code block and the complete stack trace for analysis?

Comment: made the changes, i'll check the selenium compatibility.

Comment: Have a question, how did you find "//h2[normalize-space()='Registered Succesfully']//following::td[2]" x path, i mean which element did you inspect.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked after selenium compatibility check, am bale to get the output pretty well after the wait and correct Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using absolute Xpath and webdriver is not able to locate element using it. You can try with this Xpath :

```
By.xpath("//h2[text()='Registered Succesfully']//following::tr[1]/td[1]"));
```

Comment: Thanks but this xpath is also throwing same error trace

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **form** tag which contains **table**  inside it.

You can use this XPATH :-

```
String S1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).getText();
```

or `//td[text()='Customer Name']/following-sibling::td/input`

Comment: Thanks but this xpath is also throwing same error trace

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"}

Comment: are you sure you can take input field value before submitting it ?

Comment: Sorry but am fairly new to automation and programming.Not sure what you are referring to, i believe am trying to take input value after submitting it from the "Registered successfully" page. I was trying to create the process of getting the output in a text file by simplest possible way without complicating it for a new learner like me.

Answer (score -1):

The others already said everything. I just want to add: when you have such an error, it is really helpful to check if the xpath of the element is correct. I found this answer that explains really good how: [How to verify an XPath expression in Chrome Developers tool or Firefox's Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571267/how-to-verify-an-xpath-expression-in-chrome-developers-tool-or-firefoxs-firebug)

> **Firefox**
>
> 1. Either select "Web Console" from the Web Developer submenu in the Firefox Menu (or Tools menu if you display the menu bar or are on Mac
>      OS X)
> 2. or press the Ctrl+Shift+K (Command+Option+K on OS X) keyboard shortcut.
>
>    In the command line at the bottom use the following:
>
>    - `$()`: Returns the first element that matches. Equivalent to `document.querySelector()` or calls the `$` function in the page, if it
>        exists.
>    - `$$()`: Returns an array of DOM nodes that match. This is like for `document.querySelectorAll()`, but returns an array instead of a
>        `NodeList`.
>    - `$x()`: Evaluates an XPath expression and returns an array of matching nodes.

Comment: Don't just copy (parts of) answers written by someone else.